# Automate Activity on Github to look good to potential employers

Tags: github, automation

I want to automate daily activity on my github so that when a potential employer checks out my github they will see that I've been extremely active. Can anyone suggest the most simple way to do this that would look convicing?

Comment: Yes, start supporting an open-source project and actually contribute to the community :)

Comment: I knew this would be offensive for some people, but isn't stuff like this the fun in coding? I'm busy contributing to the community picking garbage off the beach.

Comment: I don't find it offensive actually. There is nothing offensive about your question or the thing you want to do. Your end goal is to look good in front of an employer. Mimicking "coding activity" can quickly fail as the employer can skim through your commits and see that they don't add value. Hence, to reach the end goal, real contributions to the coding community stands a greater chance at impressing the people that want to hire you.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying and see your point, but its not answering my question. For me its much more about the short term fun automation goal than the getting employed goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could achieve a daily automated GitHub update is to use the GitHub API to changes that are done automatically, either through a bash script, or some other way.

In a project, pick some files that will change all the time. That might be configuration file or just create a new file with something in it every day.

You can automate this part with a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Make the cron job create/update a file every day at the same time.

Then using the [GitHub v3 api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-or-update-file-contents), you can either create/update files and push them to your repo. Again, this can be part of your cron job.

By using this API, you'll get a commit from GitHub that *should* be reflected in your contributions chart on your profile.

If we see the response from GitHub, you should get something like this, which should count as a contribution.

```
{
  "content": {
    "name": "hello.txt",
    "path": "notes/hello.txt",
    "sha": "95b966ae1c166bd92f8ae7d1c313e738c731dfc3",
    "size": 9,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/notes/hello.txt",
    .
    .
    .
  },
  "commit": {
    "sha": "7638417db6d59f3c431d3e1f261cc637155684cd",
    <more things>
    "author": { <response here>
    "committer": {  <response here>
    "message": "my commit message",
    .
    .
    .
}
```